# current density value for inductor used in boost converter

Tags: dc-dc-converter, boost

I am designing boost converter. I need to select inductor for the same. As a new bee i don't know the criteria for selecting the same. 
(1)what is the maximum current density of copper bare wire for inductor used in boost converter?
(2)what is industry standard for the same?

Answer (score 3):

There is no industry standard as far as I know. You should not need to be too concerned by the current density in the copper. What is important to you as a designer is the DC resistance of the inductor as this will give losses resulting in heat dissipation in your inductor, a too high series resistance and it will get hot !

Another VERY IMPORTANT, perhaps even MORE IMPORTANT property of the inductor is the saturation current. What current can it handle ? If the current rises above this value, the magnetic core of the inductor will saturate and the inductor will start to behave like a (low-value) resistor. The inductor will not be able to store more magnetic energy.

Usually and fortunately if you select an inductor with a sufficiently high saturation current, the copper windings will be able to handle that current :-)

Have you read this: http://powerelectronics.com/content/guide-selecting-inductors-switching-regulators?page=1  ??